# C++ Error: identifier 'class name' is undefined

Tags: c++, class

I have just started to use classes in C++. As a first object-oriented project, I want to program a character creator for a Pen and Paper game.

I have created the class structure including inheritance.

This is an example class:

```
#include "Characters.cpp"
#include "Fighter.cpp"
#include "Dwarf.cpp"

class FighterDwarf : public Characters, public Fighter, public Dwarf {

public:
    string test = "Hello, I am a fighter dwarf!";

    void testPrint() {
        cout << test << endl;
    }

    FighterDwarf() {

    }
};
```

And here is main:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FighterDwarf fighterDwarf;
    fighterDwarf.testPrint();
    return 0;
}
```

In case it is not obvious, they are in two different files/Items. I don't think it is important but they are also in two different folders.

The problem is that I get the error message "Error: identifier "FighterDwarf" is undefined.

It is most likely a beginner mistake. I would guess that I must somehow declare "FighterDwarf" in the main file before I can create an instance of the class. If this is the case, I don't know how to do that with classes.

By they way, I know that there are a lot of people out there not liking multiple inheritance but I have chosen to use C++ and not Java because of that very feature.

SOLVED:
If I want to do everything in a single file, I need to do that in the header. Which I will, as some of the classes have some more code which I don't want to rewrite right now. Furthermore, I find it easier tow work with one file than two, at least at the beginning where I have more important things to mind. But I will split the classes up into two in my very next program. By the way, why is it so important to split classes up? Isn't it easier to work with one class?

Comment: `FighterDwarf` or `DwarfFighter`? Make up your mind!

Comment: You seem to be including a `.cpp` file which is almost always wrong. You also don't see to include any headers that appear relevant to `FighterDwarf` in `main.cpp`.

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. I have checked my code and I did make it right there so that cannot be the reason for the problem especially as I have tried it with more than one class.

Comment: From what I know, you do not need to split a C++ class into a header file and a .cpp one. It find it cleaner for a start to not split it. Or am I mistaken and this only works when the class is in the same file as the main method?

Comment: It is not necessary to split them up.  But it's good practice, and a good habit to get into as soon as possible.

Comment: BTW, differentiating class names and variable names by changing letter case is bad form.  A class `FighterDwarf` and `fighterDwarf` only differ by the case of the first letter.  This may lead to coding (typos) and poor code reviews.  Please change the class name or variable name.

Comment: This code was only meant for testing. So I simply used the first name coming to my mind. Normally I would call it fighterDwarfInstance or something else if that would be more meaningful. I will avoid this kind of namings in future code examples. INevertheless, thank you for your advice. I will give it a try with headers and hope that the code will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with classes. Your main.cpp file simply needs to **#include the header file** which declares and/or defines your FighterDwarf class.

Comment: As an aside, if you've only just started using classes, be very wary of multiple inheritance.  It may seem convenient, but it's also extremely inflexible and fiddly.  In the long run it would almost certainly be better for Characters, Fighter, and Dwarf to be *members* rather than *base classes* of FighterDwarf.

Comment: OK, so you say that every class needs an header file? I know from a good tutorial that it is possible to use classes without them. However, this was only used for very, very simple ones to make the examples easier to understand. I simply wanted to avoid inconsistencies caused by splitting. Mabey that are just some old Java habits I should get rid of now. I will try it using headers. Better learn how to do things right from the beginning to avoid problems later.

Comment: And yes I have informed myself about the problems of multiple inheritance. However, the program I want to create won't be that complicated. Furthermore, I have a habit of avoiding conflicting naming. This makes it easier to change something to public if needed.

Comment: It's definitely possible to not split classes into two files, but it's only a good idea for things like template classes where you can't split them for technical reasons.  Most of the time, having a .h file with the *interface* strictly separated from a .cpp file with the *implementation* is a very good thing.  For example, any variables/functions unique to the .cpp file can't be fiddled with by people including your .h file.

Comment: Burn the tutorial.  Here's some rules of thumb:  Class declarations in separate header files that don't have ".h" extension (.h means a C language header).  Implementations, .cpp, files have the implementations of the functions and include the header file.  One pair of header and source files per object.  If you use an object in a source file, you should included its header file.

Comment: I found my program. You can put everything in one file but it has to be the header and not the cpp. I think I will keep everything in one file for this program as I have some classes with a lot more code than those examples. But why is it necessary/advisory to split them up?

Comment: The short answer is because it separates your interface from your implementation.  Anybody using your Dwarf class (including you) will use the interface in the .h/.hpp file, without them *or their compiler* knowing any of the superfluous implementation details in the .cpp file (which you can change at any time without breaking their code).  It's the sort of thing that won't matter in a tiny program, but you will be kicking yourself someday if you don't start doing this.

Comment: This convention isn't as popular in more recent languages like Java and Python because those languages have better "module" systems than C/C++'s #includes.  But even in those languages, it's still a good idea to keep public interfaces at arm's length from their implementations.

Comment: Thanks, your right it is important. I really appreciate your help. But the program I am working on is rather small and mostly for learning purposes. While I have just started using C++ object-oriented, I have used it without for some time now. So it was not that difficult for me to implement the methods of most classes. Splitting them now would take longer than finishing the program if you don't count the menu.